# When do the kernels of module homomorphisms between rings whose kernels contain a given fixed ideal contain every prime ideal over it?

Tags: linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, modules, ideals, kernels

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}$All our rings are commutative with unity and, if necessary, we can suppose that they are actually polynomial rings over a field in finitely many variables where the subring consists then in deleting one of the variables. Just in case any of these hypotheses could help.

Suppose that I have a ring $S$ that is a $R$-module over some subring $R\subseteq S$. Let $I$ be an ideal of $S$ and consider the set of $R$-module homomorphisms $$A=\{a\colon S\to R\in\Hom_{R}(S,R)\mid I\subseteq\ker(a)\}.$$

Which hypothesis can I suppose on $S$ and $R$ so I can say that the kernel $\ker(a)$ of any $R$-module homomorphism $a\in A$ contains each prime ideal $P$ of $S$ with $P\supseteq I$?

Comment: I found your title difficult to parse (it referred to homomorphisms containing ideals), so I edited it.  My result is awkward, but I couldn't come up with a more streamlined but still correct version. I hope it's all right. \\ Also, I found *hypothesising* that $S$ is an $R$-module a bit weird.  This is automatic whenever you have a subring.  So are you really just hypothesising that we have rings $S \supseteq R$?

Comment: Anyway, it seems that the requirement is that either the set of such homomorphisms is empty, or $R$ is a field.  Otherwise, pull back a non-$0$ prime ideal of $R$ to $S$ *via* any such homomorphism $a$ to obtain a prime ideal $P$ containing $I$ but not contained in $\ker(a)$.  Have I misunderstood?

Comment: @LSpice Thanks for the edit. 1. Yes, you are right: I am only hypothesising that $R\subseteq S$ but for the rest of the question is important the module setting. 2. In this sense, the pull back of a prime (ideal) of $R$ via $a\in A$ is not necessarily prime (nor an ideal) because $a$ is an $R$-module homomorphism, not a ring one. This is why the difference is important. But I might be missing something. The morphisms have to be considered in the category of $R$-modules.

Comment: Ah, [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/387541/when-do-the-kernels-of-module-homomorphisms-between-rings-whose-kernels-contain#comment988417_387541) makes sense.  Thanks for clarifying!